# Dataframe: select different index for each columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following pandas DataFrame:

from pandas import DataFrame
    from numpy import arange

```
lst = [ range(10), range(11,21), range(21,31) ]
df = DataFrame(lst).T.set_index(arange(0.1, 1.1, 0.1))

     0   1   2
0.1  0  11  21
0.2  1  12  22
0.3  2  13  23
0.4  3  14  24
0.5  4  15  25
0.6  5  16  26
0.7  6  17  27
0.8  7  18  28
0.9  8  19  29
1.0  9  20  30
```

I would like to select each column using a different index range.

For example for the column:

- 0: I would like to have only the row with index 0.6 to 0.9
- 1: I would like to have only the row with index 0.2 to 0.3
- 2: I would like to have only the row with index 0.1 to 0.3

So my DataFrame should be like this:

```
       0     1     2
0.1  NaN   NaN  21.0
0.2  NaN  12.0  22.0
0.6  5.0   NaN   NaN
0.7  6.0   NaN   NaN
0.8  7.0   NaN   NaN
0.9  8.0   NaN   NaN
```

My current solution is this one:

```
idx = array([ [0.6, 0.9], [0.2, 0.3], [0.1, 0.3] ])
df2 = DataFrame((df[col][i[0]:i[1]] for i, col in zip(idx, df))).T
```

Maybe is not the better solution.

Thanks everybody for the answers.

**Comparison**
I wrote a script to benchmark each answer.
The benchmark is divided in two:

- `STD`: answer that works only with standard index (0,1,2,3,...)
- `GEN`: answer that works with a general index

  ```
  from numpy import arange, array, linspace
  from numpy.random import rand, randint
  from pandas import DataFrame
  from timeit import Timer

  # yellowhat
  def yellowhat(df, idx):
      df2 = DataFrame((df[col][i[0]:i[1]] for i, col in zip(idx, df))).T
      return df2

  # user3483203
  def user3483203(df, idx):
      from numpy import arange
      r = arange(df.shape[0])[:, None]
      m = (idx[:,0] <= r) & (idx[:,1] > r)
      df2 = df.mask(~m).dropna(how='all')
      return df2

  def user3483203_2(df, idx):
      from numpy import zeros, bool8, arange
      def foo(a, idx):
          out = zeros(a, dtype=bool8)
          for (i, j), k in zip(idx, arange(a[1])):
              out[i:j, k] = True
          return out
      df2 = df.mask(~foo(df.shape, idx)).dropna(how='all')
      return df2

  def user3483203_mod(df, idx):
      r = df.index.values[:,None]
      m = (r >= idx[:,0]) & (r <= idx[:,1])
      df2 = df.mask(~m).dropna(how='all')
      return df2

  #
  def GeorgeLPerkins(df, idx):
      from pandas import DataFrame
      dct = {i : row for i, row in enumerate(idx)}
      df2 = DataFrame(columns = df.columns, index=df.index)
      for k in dct:
          df2[k] = df[k][dct[k][0] : dct[k][1]]
      return df2

  #
  def piRSquared(df, idx):
      tups = sorted([(i, j) for j, args in enumerate(idx) for i in range(*args)])
      df2 = df.stack().loc[tups].unstack()
      return df2

  #
  def sacul(df, idx):
      from pandas import concat
      df2 = concat([df[col].iloc[range(*idx[i])] for i,col in enumerate(df.columns)],axis=1)
      return df2

  def sacul_2(df, idx):
      df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[range(*idx[df.columns.get_loc(x.name)])])
      return df2

  # Benchmark Index STD
  nRow, nCol = 1000, 500
  df = DataFrame(rand(nRow, nCol))

  idx = df.index[randint(nRow, size=(nCol, 2))].values
  idx.sort(axis=1)

  print('STD')
  for func in [yellowhat, GeorgeLPerkins, user3483203, user3483203_2, user3483203_mod, piRSquared, sacul, sacul_2]:
      nmFunc = func.__name__
      print(nmFunc)
      t = Timer("%s(df, idx)"%nmFunc, "from __main__ import df, idx, %s"%nmFunc).timeit(10)
      print(' %8.2f sec'%t)
      print('')

  # Benchmark Index GEN
  idx = linspace(0, 1, nRow)
  df = DataFrame(rand(nRow, nCol)).set_index(idx)

  idx = idx[randint(nRow, size=(nCol, 2))]
  idx.sort(axis=1)

  print('GEN')
  for func in [yellowhat, GeorgeLPerkins, user3483203_mod]:
      nmFunc = func.__name__
      print(nmFunc)
      t = Timer("%s(df, idx)"%nmFunc, "from __main__ import df, idx, %s"%nmFunc).timeit(10)
      print(' %8.2f sec'%t)
      print('')
  ```

These are the results on my machine:

```
STD
yellowhat
     4.56 sec
GeorgeLPerkins
    26.10 sec
user3483203
     0.56 sec
user3483203_2
     0.57 sec
user3483203_mod
     0.63 sec
piRSquared
    31.84 
sacul
     6.50 
sacul_2
     7.15 sec

GEN
yellowhat
     5.13 
GeorgeLPerkins
    27.07 
user3483203_mod
     0.52 sec
```

Thanks everybody for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update***: I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793486/vectorized-approach-for-masking-individual-slices-per-column) about how to vectorize an approach to this question and @Divakar posted an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51793552/3483203) which can be applied here:

```
r = np.arange(df.shape[0])[:, None]
m = (idx[:,0] <= r) & (idx[:,1] > r)
df.mask(~m).dropna(how='all')

     0     1     2
1  NaN   NaN  22.0
2  NaN  13.0  23.0
6  6.0   NaN   NaN
7  7.0   NaN   NaN
8  8.0   NaN   NaN
```

***Old non-vectorized approach***:

This approach uses the underlying `numpy` array to create a mask:

```
def foo(a, idx):
    out = np.zeros(a, dtype=np.bool8)
    for (i, j), k in zip(idx, np.arange(a[1])):
        out[i:j, k] = True
    return out

df.mask(~foo(df.shape, idx)).dropna(how='all')
```

Output:

```
     0     1     2
1  NaN   NaN  22.0
2  NaN  13.0  23.0
6  6.0   NaN   NaN
7  7.0   NaN   NaN
8  8.0   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: use `out = np.zeros(a, dtype=np.bool8)` then `out[i:k, k] = True`

Comment: @piRSquared I asked another question to see how to vectorize this, and Divakar of course had a great solution.

Comment: That is nice.  However, broadcasting can blow out time complexity and memory.  Sometimes looping is better.

Comment: But now that I've said that, I need to back it up...  To be continued.

Comment: This solution seems interesting but what if the index are not the `standard` one like 1,2,3,... I update my question with a more generic index. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is really better than what you have, but you can iterate through your columns, unpack `index` into a range using `*`, and concatenate the resulting dataframes:

```
pd.concat([df[col].iloc[range(*index[i])] for i,col in enumerate(df.columns)],axis=1)

     0     1     2
1  NaN   NaN  22.0
2  NaN  13.0  23.0
6  6.0   NaN   NaN
7  7.0   NaN   NaN
8  8.0   NaN   NaN
```

Or another way, with apply: use the index number of each column to index your list of indexes using `df.columns.get_loc(x.name)`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[range(*index[df.columns.get_loc(x.name)])])

     0     1     2
1  NaN   NaN  22.0
2  NaN  13.0  23.0
6  6.0   NaN   NaN
7  7.0   NaN   NaN
8  8.0   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

### `stack` then select with `loc`

```
tups = sorted([(i, j) for j, args in enumerate(index) for i in range(*args)])
df.stack().loc[tups].unstack()

     0     1     2
1  NaN   NaN  22.0
2  NaN  13.0  23.0
6  6.0   NaN   NaN
7  7.0   NaN   NaN
8  8.0   NaN   NaN
```

---

### Construct new series then unstack

```
pd.Series({
    (i, j): df.at[i, j] for j, args in enumerate(index) for i in range(*args)
}).unstack()

     0     1     2
1  NaN   NaN  22.0
2  NaN  13.0  23.0
6  6.0   NaN   NaN
7  7.0   NaN   NaN
8  8.0   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your 'index' being a list, you could use a dictionary and do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [ range(10), range(11,21), range(21,31) ]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst).T
dict = {0:[6,9], 1:[2,3], 2:[1,3]}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns, index=df.index)

for k in dict:
    df2[k] = df[k][dict[k][0]:dict[k][1]+1]

print(df2)
```