# Vectorized approach for masking individual slices per column

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array:

```
>>> a = np.arange(20).reshape(5, -1)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

I have an array of regions going in order of columns, that I would like to create a boolean mask for:

```
idx = np.array([[0,2], [1,3], [2,4], [1,4]])
```

My desired mask for this set of indices is:

```
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]])
```

So column `0` has `0:2` masked, column `1` has `1:3` masked, etc.  My current approach works, but I am looking for something vectorized:

```
def foo(a, idx):
    out = np.zeros(a, dtype=np.bool8)
    for (i, j), k in zip(idx, np.arange(a[1])):
        out[i:j, k] = True
    return out
```

In action:

```
foo(a.shape, idx)

array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]])
```

Comment: This recent SO may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51736715/numpy-dynamic-slicing-per-row

Comment: Not sure how I missed that, that may be exactly what I want, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
In [434]: r = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None]

In [435]: (idx[:,0] <= r) & (idx[:,1] > r)
Out[435]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]])
```